# How do I map driver in c++?

Tags: c++

So we map driver in `C#` like this :

```
Process cmd9 = new Process();
cmd9.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd9.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd9.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
cmd9.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
cmd9.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd9.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd9.Start();
cmd9.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Windows");
cmd9.StandardInput.WriteLine("mapper.exe driver.sys");
cmd9.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
```

How do we map these drivers in `C++`?

Comment: This program does not "map a driver". What it does is starting the command line interpreter `cmd.exe` (as if you were manually going Start→Execute→cmd.exe→Run), then "type" in the commands to switch directory  (you could just as well have started with that being the process default directory) and then execute `mapper.exe` with the first argument being `driver.sys`. **Why?!** *Why are you doing it so complicated?* Just start `mapper.exe` directly, without shoehorning the rest of that crud around it.

Answer (score 1):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/system-function?view=vs-2019

```
_chdir("C:\\Windows");
system("mapper.exe driver.sys");
```